# Auth0 express-openid-connect specify IDP with connection

Tags: openid-connect, auth0, idp

I’m looking to specify a connection with auth0/express-openid-connect. We currently don’t have a user login screen with options for finding out the domain so we specify 2 different login paths 1 for our customers and 1 for our maintainers.
Passport-auth0 allows for this like so:

```
    app.get(
        '/login/google',
        passport.authenticate('auth0', {connection: 'google-oauth2'}), 
        function (req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    );
```

But as far as I can tell the new Auth0 Library (express-openid-connect) doesn’t allow specifying a connection. Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

One of the support engineers from Auth0 answered my question. It turns out you can just put it in the authorizationparameters. Code from their answer:

```
const config = {

authRequired: false,

auth0Logout: true,

authorizationParams: {

// Note: you need to provide required parameters if this object is set.

response_type: "id_token",

response_mode: "form_post",

scope: "openid profile email",

// Additional parameters

connection: "google-oauth2"

}

};
```

Thanks Auth0 team for being so responsive even if it is a newb type question!